# Entity Framework DateTime using view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following view in my DB

```
create view myview
as 
select  
      date_reception ,
      location ,
      parameter

      from mytable
```

in the model i have the following class

```
 public partial class full
 {

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_reception { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string parameter { get; set; }

 }
```

And i execute the following query in controller

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015,01,01);
var temp = (from p in db.full
            where (p.date_reception > dt)
            group p by p.parameter into g
            orderby g.Count() descending
            select new StringIntType
            {
                str = g.Key,
                nbr = g.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

After running the query keeps executing till i get this error message :

> > System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

Comment: What is `p.object` in group by clause? I don't see any such property in `full` class...!

Comment: Yes i meant parameter

Comment: What is the relation between your question header?

Comment: It's the DateTime that causes the error

Comment: What is the error message, `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException` is just an exception type

Comment: Here is it : connection timeout expired or server not responding

Comment: This mostly cause by connection problems. Check your connection string if it's fine then use SSMS to connect to the db to ensure that it's available.

Comment: Connection is fine the strange is when i use where (p.date_reception > new DateTime(2015,01,01)) it works

Comment: What is the SQL being generated (via Profiler) when you each query?  Do each of those run in the same amount of time from SSMS?

Comment: in SSMS the generated query takes more than 5 min

Comment: Did you try coalescing the nullable column to some default value, in the where clause? `where ((p.date_reception ?? DateTime.Now) > dt)` or some date in the past, according to your filter rules

Comment: perhaps if you compare the generated query for the working and the non working code, it will give you a clue as to what the difference is?

Answer (score -2):

```
public partial class full
 {

    public DateTime? date_reception { get; set; } //it's nullable
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string parameter { get; set; }

 }
```

it seems that problem is your datetime object.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParse("2015, 01, 01", out dt2))
{
   dt = dt2;
}
```